# To which extent can I answer broader without devaluing for the original asker?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I just made the following answer a question.

[Put a variable in a string PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723442/display-a-variable-in-laravel/39723628#39723628)

The question is short and shows a lack of basic language understanding from the writer. Not enough that it isn't understandable, but enough to cause some doubt.

Because of this, I decided to respond to the question, but also answer/direct the interest of future arrivals from Google, who potentially could search it up with a slightly different need.

Since I quickly got a few down-votes, I wondered if I should have been straight to the point, and only pointed out his syntax mistake, or if it was OK to elaborate the answer.

I read a few other similar meta-questions, they focus on keeping general down-voted answers, while I am looking for feedback on considering future entries to the answer.

I want to know if there is consensus towards answers that not just help the asker but also the community; for as long as the asker doesn't lose too much value? Since you could argue that this answer was broader than the asker's primary needs, but still provides value for future readers.

Comment: I can only guess that the downvotes were targetted at the initial revision of the answer, which does not really add information that wasn't already present in the existing 2 answers, and therefor considered useless.

Comment: [status-completed] The answer is no longer downvoted :)

Comment: How is it possible that the question in... question is not a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the downvotes happened after the revision, I see no reason why your answer would be downvoted. The link to the PHP docs could be a bit better, since the actual relevant documentation is behind another link in the docs you linked to (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), but that's no reason to downvote imho. It should be upvoted for being a more complete answer.

We won't know the true reason, unless the people who downvoted explain their reasoning.